# Error while connecting Wordpress Docker Container with MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I have an issue with docker.

I try to link an running mysql container with an wordpress container.

**Info about the mysql container (run-statement):**

```
docker run --name wordpressdbmysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=--- -p
4311:3306 -d mysql
```

I have to change the port because another mysql is already running and listening on port 3306. But for testing purposes I need the other/new/fresh mysql container. AFAIK there are no problems running multiple containers of the same image. That's why you can link other Containers to specific containers (like in my case wordpress to this new mysql).

**Info about the wordpress container (run-statement):**

```
docker run --name wordpress -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=--- -p 8084:80
--link wordpressdbmysql:mysql -d wordpress
```

Also here I have to change the port, because I have multiple other services running and listening on the others.

**Info about the System (via *docker info*):**

Kernel Version: 3.16.0-4-amd64

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

Now the problem. When I run the wordpress run-statement, the container starts. After about 1 minute, or after calling up the URL the container stops.

Via the statement:

```
docker logs wordpress
```

I get the following output:

```
WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now... Complete!
WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
failed: Name or service not known

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
failed: Name or service not known in - on line 19

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses:
getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 19

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
failed: Name or service not known in - on line 19

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses:
getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 19

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
failed: Name or service not known

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
failed: Name or service not known in - on line 19

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses:
getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 19
```

The output repeats about 7 to 10 times, it just says the same thing.

Sorry if this is a lame question, but I have no idea how to deal with this.

Any help is really much appreciated. And thanks in advance.

Comment: not the answer you want to hear but I just ran those two `docker run ...` commands you listed verbatim and it seems to be working for me. I can log into wordpress and it's been up and running for a while. What version of docker are you running? `docker version` will tell you

Comment: Hi Fabian, thanks for your fast response. Unfortunately today I'm not at work, so I don't have access to the docker version. At monday I give you the needed feedback.
But AFAIK I've the latest version of docker, because I set the whole VM up about 2 or 3 months ago.

Comment: For me it's working either. Probably an issue with your docker environment. Also be sure to start the wordpress container after the mysql container (and its service inside) is up.

Comment: @Fabian this was the Output:
Client:
Version:      1.11.2
API version:  1.23
Go version:   go1.5.4
Git commit:   b9f10c9
Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:23:39 2016
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
Version:      1.11.2
API version:  1.23
Go version:   go1.5.4
Git commit:   b9f10c9
Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:23:39 2016
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Comment: @lorenzvth7: I followed the plan of starting the mysql first. I tried different ports, just to be sure that none of them is blocked. I checked out my ports in use and every port I use is 100% free. I still have no idea what to do.

Comment: How did you start your first mysql container? Can you maybe add that to the question. It's difficult to reproduce because when you try this on an empty environment it works well.

Comment: So now I'm back at work. @lorenzvth7 this is the statement I used for the first mysql-Container: 
**"docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=--- -d mysql"**.
That's the normal statement described on dockerhub for the mysql Container.
Is it possible to run two containers on the same port?

Comment: It's possible to run 2 containers on the same internal port but you'll have to map the port to a different port. So for example you can run 2 mysql instances which are opening 3306 on its own containers but you have to map them on different ports if you want to expose the port. For your case above: if the 2 containers are running on the same host you can just link your wordpress container without mapping the 3306 of your mysql container on 4311 (all the traffic is 'inside' the host, so wordpress will connect with 3306 internal instead of going outside en inside (4311))

Comment: That what's I've already did I think. Isn't this statement: -p 4311:3306 the mapping of the ports? Because the mysql works fine with other Services at the same time, but it causes problems when connecting wordpress with it. For example I have also connected redmine to the mysql container and it works quite fine.